# How to password protect a subdomain?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a proxy server on my website that is password protected. It is located at www.domain.com/proxy (/var/www/html/proxy) I set up a new subdomain (proxy.domain.com) and configured apache to serve (/var/www/html/proxy) however it is not password protected when accessing it throught the subdomain, but it is through the directory on the main domain. How can I go about making this work? Im running Apache 2 on Ubuntu 16.04

Comment: configure the auth the same way you did for the other virtualhost.

Comment: Ah yes, didn't know it was a seperate config file. Im pretty new to all this. Thank you